# Iterative implementation of alpha beta tree search

Tags: c#, tree, search

This is an iterative implementation of alpha beta tree search in C#. Please help me confirm the correctness of my code. `search()` is called when the search begins.

```
int depth;
Func<board, int> value;
Func<board, List<string>> legalmoves;

Random randomgenerator = new Random();

board board;

Stack<int> alphas = new Stack<int>();
Stack<int> betas = new Stack<int>();
Stack<int> calllevels = new Stack<int>();
Stack<string> nodesleft = new Stack<string>();
Stack<string> callstack = new Stack<string>();


void search()
{
    alphas.Push(int.MinValue);
    betas.Push(int.MaxValue);
    pushlegalmoves();
    //initialize the alpha, beta, and push all legal moves
    while (nodesleft.Any())
    {
        string currentnode = nodesleft.Pop();
        int calllevel = calllevels.Count;
        int movesleft = calllevels.Pop();
        callstack.Push(currentnode);
        move(currentnode);
        //extract all information about the node and play the move
        if (calllevel != depth)
        {
            calllevels.Push(movesleft);
            alphas.Push(alphas.First());
            betas.Push(betas.First());
            pushlegalmoves();
            //expand the tree if not terminal(aka not enough depth here)
        }
        else
        {
            if (calllevel % 2 == 0) max(calllevel, movesleft, currentnode);
            else min(calllevel, movesleft, currentnode);
            //cleanup and process everything if node is terminal
        }
    }
}
void max(int calllevel, int movesleft, string currentnode)
//cleans up and processes tree, starting from a max player terminal node
{
    bool color = true;
    bool cleanup = false;
    //color means which player is the function currently processing. true = max player, false = min player
    //cleanup means whether to process the the search tree up to the next level
    int score = value(board);
    if (score >= betas.First())
    {
        cleanup = true;
        score = betas.First();
    }
    if (score > alphas.First())
    {
        alphas.Pop();
        alphas.Push(score);
    }
    if (movesleft == 1) cleanup = true;
    unmove(callstack.Pop());
    //changes the alpha and beta values. if the move is last move or a beta cutoff is issued, then clean up the current tree level. undo the current move.
    while (cleanup)
    {
        color = !color;
        cleanup = false;
        //change the player. reset whether to clecan up
        for (; movesleft > 0; movesleft--)
        {
            nodesleft.Pop();
        }
        movesleft = calllevels.Pop();
        unmove(callstack.Pop());
        alphas.Pop();
        betas.Pop();
        //climbing up the next level
        if (color)
        {
            if (score >= betas.First())
            {
                cleanup = true;
                score = betas.First();
            }
            if (score > alphas.First())
            {
                alphas.Pop();
                alphas.Push(score);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (score <= alphas.First())
            {
                cleanup = true;
                score = alphas.First();
            }
            if (score < betas.First())
            {
                betas.Pop();
                betas.Push(score);
            }
        }
        if (movesleft == 1) cleanup = true;
        //processing the next level and deciding whether to keep cleaning up
    }
    calllevels.Push(movesleft - 1);
    //puts in the correct number of unprocessed moves
}
void min(int calllevel, int movesleft, string currentnode)
//cleans up and processes tree, starting from a min player terminal node
{
    bool color = false;
    bool cleanup = false;
    //color means which player is the function currently processing. true = max player, false = min player
    //cleanup means whether to process the the search tree up to the next level
    int score = -value(board);
    if (score <= alphas.First())
    {
        cleanup = true;
        score = alphas.First();
    }
    if (score < betas.First())
    {
        betas.Pop();
        betas.Push(score);
    }
    if (movesleft == 1) cleanup = true;
    unmove(callstack.Pop());
    //changes the alpha and beta values. if the move is last move or a alpha cutoff is issued, then clean up the current tree level. undo the current move.
    while (cleanup)
    {
        color = !color;
        cleanup = false;
        //change the player. reset whether to clecan up
        for (; movesleft > 0; movesleft--)
        {
            nodesleft.Pop();
        }
        movesleft = calllevels.Pop();
        unmove(callstack.Pop());
        alphas.Pop();
        betas.Pop();
        //climbing up the next level
        if (color)
        {
            if (score >= betas.First())
            {
                cleanup = true;
                score = betas.First();
            }
            if (score > alphas.First())
            {
                alphas.Pop();
                alphas.Push(score);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (score <= alphas.First())
            {
                cleanup = true;
                score = alphas.First();
            }
            if (score < betas.First())
            {
                betas.Pop();
                betas.Push(score);
            }
        }
        if (movesleft == 1) cleanup = true;
        //processing the next level and deciding whether to keep cleaning up
    }
    calllevels.Push(movesleft - 1);
    //puts in the correct number of unprocessed moves
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Readability

The indentation is good and you have good variable names, but some of them are hard to read. Why? More or less because they're lowercase. [Variables and parameters should be camelCase.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)

- calllevels >> callLevels
- nodesleft >> nodesLeft
- callstack >> callStack

Method names like `search` and `max` should be PascalCase. In other words, `Search` and `Max`.

---

This could use some braces.

```
else
{
    if (calllevel % 2 == 0) max(calllevel, movesleft, currentnode);
    else min(calllevel, movesleft, currentnode);
    //cleanup and process everything if node is terminal
}
```

It seems like a minor thing, but if you go to change it later, and forget to add braces then, it could cause trouble.

---

I'm not a big fan of for loops without an index declared right in it. Opt for a while loop instead.

```
for (; movesleft > 0; movesleft--)
{
    nodesleft.Pop();
}
```

Vs

```
while (movesLeft > 0) 
{
    nodesLeft.Pop();
    movesLeft--;
}
```

---

It's not obvious to me how to fix it, but there should be some way to clean up the seeming duplication here. It should be possible to write a single function to do this work. Perhaps it takes a boolean parameter. I'm not sure, but I know there's a way.

```
                if (color)
                {
                    if (score >= betas.First())
                    {
                        cleanup = true;
                        score = betas.First();
                    }
                    if (score > alphas.First())
                    {
                        alphas.Pop();
                        alphas.Push(score);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (score <= alphas.First())
                    {
                        cleanup = true;
                        score = alphas.First();
                    }
                    if (score < betas.First())
                    {
                        betas.Pop();
                        betas.Push(score);
                    }
                }
```

---

Here is some duplication that we can pretty easily fix. There are *a lot* of places where you Pop an item off the stack and immediately push the score on. Replace every instance of it with a method. It's a small step toward DRYing this up.

```
private void PopThenPushScore(Stack<int> stack, int score)
{
    stack.Pop();
    stack.Push(score);
}
```

Comment: I know this isn't the help you're really looking for, but maybe the bump will help the question gain some attention from someone who *can* actually help.